# Parse.com - Cloud function call from another cloud function makes request.user null

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I've written a Cloud function ("newUserLog") that i call from the iOS SDK and everything works correctly. the cloud function heavily uses "request.user".

Now i've made another cloud function ("doStats"), and in that function at some scenarios, i need to call "newUserLog" function.

I do this with 
Parse.Cloud.run("newUserLog").then(function(logCreated){ 
...
});

But at "newUserLog" function, request.user is null.
What is the best practice to solve this kind of problem? i know i can pass the request.user pointer and fetch it again, but i'm afraid it's less secure and i'll have to do alot of refactoring.

Is there a simple way transferring request.user from one cloud function to another?

Thanks alot
Or

Answer (score 0):

Don't call one cloud function from another if you can help it. Instead, create plain JS functions which hold your reusable logic and pass them a set of parameters. This is much easier to manage and much clearer about what those functions actually need in order to operate.

Answer (score 0):

change newUserLog code to be something like:

```
var user;
if( request.User )
{
    user = request.User;
}
else
{
    user = new Parse.User();
    user.id = request.params.userId;
}
```

In both cases you have basically the shell of the user, and will need to perform a fetch if you want the rest of the data.

Change your doStats method to pass in the userId as a parameter to the other cloud code function:

```
Parse.Cloud.run("newUserLog", {userId:request.User.id});
```

or

```
var user = request.User;
Parse.Cloud.run("newUserLog", {userId:user.id});
```

That being said, you could consider creating a function that gets called by both doStats and newUserLog that is not a cloud code function, and pass relevant parameters into it from either of your cloud code functions.